# Textparsing and splitting text including/excluding quotation marks

Tags: c#, regex, quotes, escaping

My question is almost identical to an earlier entry I found here but not quite.

I need to parse through a textfile where the data is structured in this way:
Each item in the file begins with a `#` followed by the label.
The fields in the post is separated by one or more whitespaces.

Here comes the part I'm having problem with.
Each field may or may not me enclosed by quotation marks, it's only required if the data contains spaces.

So what I'm after is a regex that splits by whitespace but not if that whitespace is inside a quotation.

At the moment I'm using a separate regex for each label and then but it would be much more efficient to split it immediatly when reading from the file.
As for the account example below `(^#[A-z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s(.+)`

Example of data

```
#ACCOUNT 7059 "Misc. travelexpenses"
#ADRESS "M. Jackson" "somewhere over the rainbow" WI53233-1704 555-12345
```

Comment: Could there be quotes embedded inside quoted strings, and if so, how will they be escaped, i.e. `"Two by four (2""x4"")"` or `"Two by four (2\"x4\")"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an "OR" construct, to define possible forms of the fields.
Like

```
([A-z]+|"[^"]+")
```

matches both Kring and "Mr. Kring".

**Edit:** So, to get all your fields and the label in the above records you could use

```
(?:^#|\s+)([^"#\s]+|"[^"]+")
```

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is a good way to test Regular Expressions.

Comment: Use `\S+` instead of `[A-z]+`

Comment: \S hits non-whitespace characters, doesn't it?
Well.. looking at the data given above, that might be what Kring was looking for. I just wanted to show how to use the or construct.

Comment: But what if I want to exclude a match? In this case find all whitespaces except those within quotation marks.

This is a question : Splits to 4 parts
This is "a question" : Splits to 3 parts

Comment: Just switch it around: `("[^"]+"|\S+)`

Comment: Excuse me for being so dense, but isn't that the exact opposite of what I was asking? But maybe it is close enough :) Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't initially sure if there could be more than two fields per record. I'll update my answer, to match your records above.